# API integration to Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, api, plugins, wordpress-theming

Recently I've purchased a wordpress theme(resideo), installed it's plugin and now it is running well. I connected the website with an API via the software plugin I'm using (JUSTIMMO plugin), but it is showing a default style, with not so many options to edit it (only with external css).

How do I change the style of the API plugin completely, or use an existing style for it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the api results to the current theme if you set-up a new theme folder with new function.php file and new theme layout.

Comment: thanks for your attempt on answering the question. It will be more helpful for OP if you add a little more to your answer like how to set up a new theme (or child-theme?) and etc.